# Scala Splitting Code

Tags: java, scala, oop

I am working on to design a Domain Specific Language for a given set of code. 
I am having a exampleMNIST object file with the following code and imports

```
package fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.apps
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.core.ConnectionIndex
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.core.actors.Config
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.core.models.properties.MembranePotentialThreshold
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.features.builder.N2S3
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.features.builder.connection.types.FullConnection
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.features.io.input._
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.features.logging.graph.{SynapticWeightSelectGraph, SynapticWeightSelectGraphRef}
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.models.neurons.LIF
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.models.synapses.{InhibitorySynapse, QBGParameters, SimplifiedSTDP}
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.support.N2S3ResourceManager
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.support.UnitCast._
import squants.electro.ElectricPotentialConversions.ElectricPotentialConversions


object  ExampleMnist extends App {
  implicit val timeout = Config.longTimeout

  QBGParameters.alf_m = 0.005f
  QBGParameters.alf_p = 0.01f
  QBGParameters.beta_m = 2f
  QBGParameters.beta_p = 2f

  val n2s3 = new N2S3("N2S3")

  val inputStream = InputMnist.Entry >> SampleToSpikeTrainConverter[Float, InputSample2D[Float]](0, 22, 150 MilliSecond, 350 MilliSecond) >> N2S3Entry
//  val inputLayer = n2s3.createInput(Mnist.distributedInput("data/train2k-images.idx3-ubyte", "data/train2k-labels.idx1-ubyte"))
  val inputLayer = n2s3.createInput(inputStream)
  val dataFile = N2S3ResourceManager.getByName("mnist-train-images").getAbsolutePath
  val labelFile =  N2S3ResourceManager.getByName("mnist-train-labels").getAbsolutePath
  inputStream.append(InputMnist.DataFrom(dataFile, labelFile))

  val unsupervisedLayer = n2s3.createNeuronGroup()
    .setIdentifier("Layer1")
    .setNumberOfNeurons(30)
    .setNeuronModel(LIF, Seq(
      (MembranePotentialThreshold, 35 millivolts)))

  inputLayer.connectTo(unsupervisedLayer, new FullConnection(() => new SimplifiedSTDP))
  unsupervisedLayer.connectTo(unsupervisedLayer, new FullConnection(() => new InhibitorySynapse))

  n2s3 create()

  val inputToClassifierIndex = new ConnectionIndex(inputLayer, unsupervisedLayer)

  n2s3.addNetworkObserver(new SynapticWeightSelectGraphRef(
    for(outputIndex <- 0 until unsupervisedLayer.shape.getNumberOfPoints) yield {
      for(inputX <- 0 until InputMnist.shape.dimensions(0)) yield {
        for(inputY <- 0 until InputMnist.shape.dimensions(1)) yield {
          val input = inputLayer.getNeuronPathAt(inputX, inputY)
          val output = unsupervisedLayer.getNeuronPathAt(outputIndex)
          inputToClassifierIndex.getConnectionsBetween(input, output).head
        }
      }
    },
    SynapticWeightSelectGraph.heatMap,
    4,
    100)
  )

  println("Start Training ...")
  n2s3.runAndWait()

  val dataTestFile = N2S3ResourceManager.getByName("mnist-test-images").getAbsolutePath
  val labelTestFile =  N2S3ResourceManager.getByName("mnist-test-labels").getAbsolutePath

  inputStream.append(InputMnist.DataFrom(dataTestFile, labelTestFile))

  println("Start Testing ...")
  unsupervisedLayer.fixNeurons()
  val benchmarkMonitor = n2s3.createBenchmarkMonitor(unsupervisedLayer)

  n2s3.runAndWait()
  println(benchmarkMonitor.getResult.evaluationByMaxSpiking)
  benchmarkMonitor.exportToHtmlView("test.html")

  n2s3.destroy()
}
```

So I decided to write another object file in the same package in which the current file is present with function names easy to understand by a third user.I created a object-file named `test` in the same package.

```
package fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.apps
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.core.actors.Config
import fr.univ_lille.cristal.emeraude.n2s3.models.synapses.{InhibitorySynapse, QBGParameters, SimplifiedSTDP}
object test {
  def Configure_Actors_With_Timeout_Value {
    implicit val timeout = Config.longTimeout}

  def Set_Parameters_for_MNIST =
  {
  QBGParameters.alf_m = 0.005f
  QBGParameters.alf_p = 0.01f
  QBGParameters.beta_m = 2f
  QBGParameters.beta_p = 2f} **/
}
}
```

Now I want to create the same functions in the `test` object file and simply call them in the `exampleMNIST` file.
So I created a definition `Configure_Actors_With_Timeout_Value` in the test object file. So in the `exampleMNIST` file, whenever I replace the `implicit val timeout = Config.longTimeout`line with `test.Configure_Actors_With_Timeout_Value` everything works fine but when I try to replace the QBGParameters part with the `test.Set_Parameters_for_MNIST` it throws an error.

I know it's a simple question but I am a newbie with Scala , please guide me.

Comment: I'd say writing a good DSL is not a simple task and you might want to start with something more basic. Even if calling test.Configure_Actors_With_Timeout_Value doesn't fail to compile, it will also not do anything as the function returns `Unit`.

Comment: Yeah I can understand that's why I need help on that part.